# Run a function in real time on Excel Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I need some idea to make this function update in real time. This function count the color of the cells for a work I need.

```
Function COUNTCOLOR(celdaOrigen As Range, rango As Range)

Application.Volatile

Dim celda As Range

For Each celda In rango

    If celda.Interior.Color = celdaOrigen.Interior.Color Then
        COUNTCOLOR = COUNTCOLOR + 1
    End If

Next celda

End Function
```

I already try to run this function

```
Application.CalculateFullRebuild
```

But It didn't work in real time, I had to assign that function to a button and when I want to update the cells which count the colors I press the button, but that's not what I want. I want the cells count the colors in real time, I want they show me the number immediately I change a color. The cell that count the color has the following formula:

```
=COUNTCOLOR(A1;A1:A9998)
```

Where "A1" is a cell of the color I want the cell counts (like a sample), and the "A1:A9998" is the range where I want the formula find the color a the previous assigned sample. The cell will show a number of the cells in the range with the color of the sample.

I hop this information I provided can help you to give me a good answer :)

Thank you so much!

Comment: There is no built-in 'event' that is triggered by a change in a cell's color. You would need to build your own from the application's message queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert a class module and name it ClsMonitorOnupdate

Put in the code below

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents objCommandBars As Office.CommandBars
Private rMonitor As Range
Public Property Set Range(ByRef r As Range): Set rMonitor = r: End Property
Public Property Get Range() As Range: Set Range = rMonitor: End Property
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set objCommandBars = Application.CommandBars
End Sub
Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set objCommandBars = Nothing
End Sub
Private Sub objCommandBars_OnUpdate()
    If ActiveWorkbook.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then Exit Sub
    If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then Exit Sub
    If Intersect(Selection, rMonitor) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
rMonitor.Dirty 'dosomething to trigger your function
End Sub
```

In the ThisWorkbooksection you put:

```
Option Explicit
Private Const sRanges As String = "A1:A100" 'adjust to your range Rango?
Private Const sSheet As String = "YourSheetName" 'adjust to your sheetname
Private cMonitor As ClsMonitorOnupdate

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Set cMonitor = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set cMonitor = New ClsMonitorOnupdate
    Set cMonitor.Range = Sheets(sSheet).Range(sRanges)
End Sub
```

Adjust your Sheetname and range to monitor, after running the WorkBookopen event your range(s) will be monitored and a color-change will recalculate your Countcolor function (you can leave application.volatile out of it)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, it's not the most elegant solution, but it works. The idea is to run the Sub every 5-10 seconds to make it work in real time.

Here is the code:

```
Sub COUNTCOLOR()

    Dim RunTime
    Dim COUNTCOLOR As Integer
    Dim celda As Range

    Dim lastRow As Variant
        lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim rango As Range
    Set rango = Range("A1:A" & lastRow)

    For Each celda In rango

        'Compare cell interior color with cell A1
        If celda.Interior.Color = Cells(1, "A").Interior.Color Then
            COUNTCOLOR = COUNTCOLOR + 1
        End If

        Cells(1, "C").Value = COUNTCOLOR

    Next celda

    'To run sub every 5 seconds
    RunTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
    Application.OnTime RunTime, "COUNTCOLOR"

End Sub
```

Comment: The timer approach is probably the best workaround possible. This solution could just be a little tidier. Volatile has no effect on subroutines; RefreshAll isn't required if there isn't external data; and COUNTCOLOR should be an Integer to return 0 by default if there are no cells with matching color. Turning off ScreenUpdating also isn't required when just updating the value of one cell.

Comment: That was a very good solution, but due to my requirement I think is not workable, I really appreciate your effort on help me. I was wonder if in my original code, I can add something to make it run again (recalculate) each time I use the "Save Button" Do you think is this possible?. I think it could be a good solution for me too! ;)

Comment: Then you can use the Workbook_BeforeSave event, I'll post another solution below